# Функция system в C++

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

Смотрю [описание функции `system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) и заметил два странных места:

> If *command* is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be the status code returned by the called command, if supported.

Что подразумевается под *"generally expected"?* В каких случаях может оказаться, что возвращаемое значение не является кодом возврата? И чем оно тогда является?

> If *command* is not a *null pointer*, it causes *undefined behavior*.

Но ведь функция для того и нужна, чтобы выполнять команды, которые, очевидно, не null. О каком же неопределённом поведении и при каких условиях идёт речь?

PS: [В другом источнике](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) возвращаемое значение вообще не связывается с выполняемой командой (если она не null) - говорится просто *"Implementation-defined value".* И никаких упоминаний про UB.

Comment: Ну, в первом случае, возможно, имеется в виду, *как мне кажется*, что вы можете возвращать что угодно - и это что угодно может иметь очень малое отношение к состоянию программы. Например, при сбое возвращать 0, а при нормальном возврате - 2. А может, реализация `system` вообще не в состоянии отслеживать код возврата вызываемого приложения - ну вот такая операционка досталась... А UB - ну, в том плане, что когда вы пытаетесь выполнить что угодно - то что угодно может произойти :) Нет? imho, понятно...

Comment: @Harry, ну обычно UB означает, что функцию можно и не вызывать))

Comment: У нее точно сказано, что она делает и что возвращает для нулевого указателя, так ведь? А как описать, что она будет делать для ненулевого? Описать - для всех времен и наро... операционных систем?

Comment: @Harry, но даже если так, это ж implementation-defined, а не undefined.

Comment: Ну не знаю... В этом случае должно быть точно описано, что будет происходить *в данной реализации*, но ведь опять же, не опишешь все возможное результаты для всех возможных строк?...

Comment: @Harry, наличие UB делает всю программу невалидной. Получается, что любая программа, вызывающая system со строкой невалидна. Очевидно, что это не так.

Comment: Кстати, случайно наткнулся вот на это: https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/09/why-undefined-behavior-may-call-never.html (!). Чуть не выпал в осадок. И ведь действительно, Clang ведет себя именно так!

Comment: @AnT, а это в самом деле круто! Похоже, что реализации оптимизаторов зашли куда-то не туда...

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вообще, то что вы написали это уже крестовая самодеятельность. В оригинале -- `If command is NULL, then system() returns a status indicating whether
       a shell is available on the system.` (если [man system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) из Линукса, который `CONFORMING TO     POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, C89, C99` считать оригиналом) (понятно, там есть свои тараканы, но не до степени UB)

Comment: @avp: Стандарт С говорит фактически то же самое про `system(NULL)`. Вопрос Qwertiy об UB относится именно к ситуации, когда параметр `system` **не** является нулевым указателем.

Comment: @avp, дык разговор про случай если команда **не** `NULL`... но в Си и в этом случае всё чёрным по белому — implementation-defined...

Comment: а меня одно смущает что про UB написано в разделе про исключения? ИМХО всё это очень смахивает на простую описку...

Comment: @AnT, при невызываемую функцию я перевод на хабре читал - весёленькая история :)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, если **не NULL**, то интерпретация возвращаемого system числа распадается на 3 случая: 1) не удалось создать новый процесс -- *код возврата* `-1`; 2) не удалось запустить shell -- *статус завершения* (output argument из waitpid()) `127`; 3) *статус завершения* от shell (imho   надежно отличить 2) от 3) сложно)

Comment: @avp, имеешь в виду, что в плюсах и в чистом си функция может работать по-разному? Это же вроде одна и та же функция, как на неё могут быть разные требования?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, несколько смущает, но я не в курсе, в каком разделе они обычно пишут.

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет, функции наверняка работают одинаково, а вот головы у *писателей документации* по разному

Comment: @AnT: Вот классика по этому поводу: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html, http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html, http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html, ну и https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если посмотреть в черновик стандарта С++ (N4791), то можно найти всего лишь пару скудных упоминаний функции `system`.

1. В разделе 16.2.2, описывающем заголовочный файл `<cstdlib>`. И там просто представлена её сигнатура:

   ```
   int system(const char* string);
   ```
2. В разделе 16.12 *Other runtime support*:

   > Headers `<csetjmp>` (nonlocal jumps), `<csignal>` (signal handling), `<cstdarg>` (variable arguments), and `<cstdlib>` (runtime environment `getenv`, `system`), provide further compatibility with C code.

Собственно, из п.2. становится ясно, что искать описание надо уже в сишном стандарте. Ну а там (С11) мы видим следующее (7.22.4.8):

> **Description**
>
> If **string** is a null pointer, the **system** function determines whether the host
>   environment has a *command processor*. If **string** is not a null pointer, the **system** function passes the string pointed to by **string** to that command processor to be executed in a manner which the implementation shall document; this might then cause the program calling **system** to behave in a non-conforming manner or to terminate.
>
> **Returns**
>
> If the argument is a null pointer, the **system** function returns nonzero only if a
>   command processor is available.  If the argument is not a null pointer, and the **system** function does return, it returns an implementation-defined value.

Можно заметить, что никаких упоминаний UB тут нет, но есть требование к реализации предоставить соответствующую документацию о том, как должен работать командный процессор, вызванный через `system` и есть ли он вообще. А еще есть фраза очень похожая по возможному исходу на UB:

> ... to behave in a non-conforming manner or to terminate.

Мой перевод:

> ... вести себя несоответствующим образом или завершиться.

Но в силу того, что это всё отдано на откуп реализации - это не является UB с точки зрения стандарта языка.

Т.о. в случае затруднений с интерпретацией всё же стоит обращаться к стандарту (хотя бы черновику), а не рассчитывать на описания с других сайтов. Ради интереса я посмотрел в web архиве [версию страницы cplusplus.com от ноября 2012 года](https://web.archive.org/web/20121129042708/http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) и там про UB тоже ничего нет. Вполне допускаю, что в текущей версии страницы просто решили таким простым образом расшифровать вышеупомянутую мной фразу. Например, ситуация с `system(nullptr)` является переносимой, а всё остальное - нет и жди беды.

Насчёт *"generally expected"* вроде бы уже ответили, суть в том, чтобы не перекладывать поведение системы, где будет выполняться скомпилированный код, на стандарт языка, поэтому предложен некий наиболее известный случай. А что там понапишут какие-то другие реализации, и что в них должен значить этот код - дело уже самих реализаций, а не языка С.

Answer (score 5):

1. В общем случае язык не требует, чтобы в среде выполнения вообще существовало такое понятие, как "код возврата команды". Может в командном процессоре среды выполнения никакого "кода возврата" не поддерживается вообще или используемый подход к возврату статуса завершения не является натурально совместимым с типом `int`. Поэтому навязывать такое требование спецификация языка не может/не хочет.

   P.S. Спецификация такого поведения по своей общей сути аналогична, например, спецификации преобразований между указательными и целыми типами. Всем понятно, что в общем и целом *ожидается* просто преобразование значения адреса. Но спецификация языка не оговаривает деталей внутреннего представления указателей и не хочет навязывать такое поведение.
2. Откуда взялось упоминание про "undefined behavior" - надо разбираться. В стандарте языка я такого прямого утверждения не вижу. Хотя определенная логичность в нем есть: выполнение команды командным процессором может привести к каким угодно результатам и описание поведения таких команд выходит за рамки implementation-defined.

Comment: Разве наличие UB в программе не делает её невалидной? Но ведь программу, использующую `system` называть невалидной только за это неверно?